# How to Handle Download or Response as File on Inappbrowser Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Guys, Help me For handled Reponse File on My Cordova application, My application when device ready has load On web, and  i want when click file or download on web the file enter to my app or my storage mobile, link download file on web not while .pdf or extension just link with parameter and response file, Help me

Answer (score 0):

I tried Add line : YourDirectoryCordovaApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java

```
     this.inAppWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
      //  DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) inAppWebView.getContext().getSystemService(inAppWebView.getContext().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        dm.enqueue(request);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

And Great...success download, But How with Plugin Cordova for download on inappbrowser please, tell me name of plugin to download respone file ?